# ODBC connection successful, PyODBC returns error

Tags: python, mysql, connection, odbc, pyodbc

I have set up my remote MySQL database connection with ODBC. The username, password, server address and port are all defined and the connection is successful when I press *Test*.

When I try this with Python, where my connection statement is referring to the ODBC DSN I just made:

```
connection = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.3 Unicode Driver};DSN=my_ODBC_DSN;DATABASE=my_database_schema;UID=user;PWD=password")
cursor = connection.cursor()
```

This works for a local database, but for a remote database on a dedicated server, I get the following error:

```
pyodbc.Error: ('HY000', "[HY000] [MySQL][ODBC 5.3(w) Driver]Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: YES) (1045)
(SQLDriverConnect); [HY000] [MySQL][ODBC 5.3(w) Driver]Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: YES) (1045)")
```

I can't figure out what the problem is. There seems to be a problem with the connnection between Python and the ODBC link to my remote database.

Comment: Which OS are you using? In case of Windows, are you modifying the correct DSN corresponding to your version of Python (i.e. 32- or 64-bit)?

Comment: Well, I have a local database running  as well and this database is also configured in ODBC. I experience no problems while connecting to the local database with pyodbc.